# How to create mini cms with OOP?

Tags: php, oop

Im using OOP and im new with that. I just dont get it...i tryed everything and i just can't make a simple text edit, for ex:

I want to make a form where i can edit text from main page. So for ex i want to edit footer text "copyright by bla bla" i want to edit that by using simple form. It sounds easy but for me with oop...its not that much.

This is example of my register/login system and i tryed to make it similar to this but can't figure it out.

```
class DB{
private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo,
        $_query,
        $_error = false,
        $_results,
        $_count = 0;

private function __construct(){
    try{
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)){
            foreach($params as $param){
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()){
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function action($action, $table, $where = array()){
    if(count($where) === 3){
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator   = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function get($table, $where){
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}

public function delete($table, $where){
    return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
}

public function insert($table, $fields = array()){
    $keys = array_keys($fields);
    $values = null;
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $field){
        $values .= '?';
        if($x < count($fields)){
            $values .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function update($table, $id, $fields){
    $set = '';
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $name => $value){
        $set .= "{$name} = ?";
        if($x < count($fields)){
            $set .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function results(){
    return $this->_results;
}

public function first(){
    return $this->results()[0];
}

public function error(){
    return $this->_error;
}

public function count(){
    return $this->_count;
}
```

}

Comment: that's a lot of code for us to read through where are you specifically stuck?

Comment: @Dagon There is no problem with that code, its just an example what i need. I need help making simple cms to edit text from page (using OOP). There is nothing wrong with the code i gave you, thats just an example from login/register system that is based on OOP.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @Dagon I just need help because i dont know how to make that. Its stupid for me to say "can you make for me that?" but i want some examples or something because im new with oop. I hope you understand me what i need.